# How to perform Tukey comparisons with linear model including three double interaction terms?

Tags: r, model, interaction, tukey

I'm trying to analyse some data where I have three explanatory variables named `Estimulo`, `Velocida`, and `Viendocon` (all of them to be taken as factors) and one response variable, named `Vueltasmin`, which is a numeric one.

As I measure Vueltasmin after various conditions, I use a linear mixed model where the variable `Bicho` (i.e: the subject) is a random-effect variable indicating measures aren't independent regarding one subject.

To make the model simpler, I included all three possible double-interactions between my variables (`Estimulo * Viendocon, Estimulo * Velocidad and Velocidad * Viendocon`) but not the three-variable-interaction (`Estimulo * Velocidad * Viendocon`) (Named `m1`), and in order to compliance with normality and equality of variances I had to remove some data points, so the model I finally use is named “m1bis”.

As I try to perform Tukey multiple comparison method, I had to re-write the model naming my variables as `int1`, `int2`, and `int3`, which are all three double interactions.

Then, R is able to perform the first Tukey comparison, regarding int1, but not the second and third, and here is my problem: I want to make all three comparisons as the summary (m1bis) shows all double interactions are statistically significant and I can't analyse the principal effect of my variables.

The error I get is as follows:

```
Error in Ktotal[count:(count + nrow(h$K) - 1), h$where] <- h$K :number of     items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Here is the script I'm running:

```
m1bis <- lmer(Vueltasmin~Velocidad+Estimulo+Viendocon+Velocidad*Viendocon+Velocidad*Estimulo+Viendocon*Estimulo + (1|Bicho), data = Datosm1bis)
summary(m1bis)

e1bis<-resid(m1bis) 

pred1bis<-predict(m1bis) 
windows()
par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
plot(pred1bis, e1bis, xlab="Predichos", ylab="Residuos de pearson",main="Gráfico de dispersión de RE vs PRED",cex.main=.8 ) #Grafico RP vs predichos para ver ausencia de patrones
abline(0,0)
qqnorm(e1bis, cex.main=.8)   
qqline(e1bis)
par(mfrow = c(1, 1))
shapiro.test(e1bis)


model.matrix.gls <- function(object, ...) {
model.matrix(terms(object), data = getData(object), ...)
}
model.frame.gls <- function(object, ...) {
model.frame(formula(object), data = getData(object), ...)
}
terms.gls <- function(object, ...) {
terms(model.frame(object), ...)
}



Datosm1bis['int1'] <- with(Datosm1bis, interaction(Estimulo,Viendocon))
Datosm1bis['int2'] <- with(Datosm1bis, interaction(Estimulo,Velocidad))
Datosm1bis['int3'] <- with(Datosm1bis, interaction(Velocidad,Viendocon))

m1bisbis <- lmer(Vueltasmin~int1+int2+int3 + (1|Bicho), data = Datosm1bis)
summary(m1bisbis)

tukeyINT<-glht(m1bisbis,linfct=mcp(int1="Tukey"))
summary(tukeyINT)
cld(tukeyINT)

tukeyINT2<-glht(m1bisbis,linfct=mcp(int2="Tukey"))
summary(tukeyINT2)
cld(tukeyINT2)

tukeyINT3<-glht(m1bisbis,linfct=mcp(int3="Tukey"))
summary(tukeyINT3)
cld(tukeyINT3)
```

Here is a sample of my data base (**please ignore the Ganancia column**):

```
Bicho   Velocidad   Viendocon   Estimulo    Vueltasmin  Ganancia
92  Uno Derecho Horario 1   1
93  Uno Derecho Horario 0.916666667 0.916666667
94  Uno Derecho Horario 1.333333333 1.333333333
95  Uno Derecho Horario 0   0
96  Uno Derecho Horario 0.833333333 0.833333333
97  Uno Derecho Horario 0.833333333 0.833333333
98  Uno Derecho Horario 0.5 0.5
100 Uno Derecho Horario 0   0
101 Uno Derecho Horario 0.5 0.5
102 Uno Derecho Horario 0.333333333 0.333333333
103 Uno Derecho Horario 1.083333333 1.083333333
104 Uno Derecho Horario 0   0
105 Uno Derecho Horario 0.333333333 0.333333333
106 Uno Derecho Horario 0.333333333 0.333333333
108 Uno Derecho Horario 1.333333333 1.333333333
109 Uno Derecho Horario 0.833333333 0.833333333
110 Uno Derecho Horario 0.083333333 0.083333333
111 Uno Derecho Horario 1   1
92  Uno Derecho Antihorario 0   0
93  Uno Derecho Antihorario -0.166666667    -0.166666667
94  Uno Derecho Antihorario 0.166666667 0.166666667
95  Uno Derecho Antihorario 0   0
96  Uno Derecho Antihorario 0.083333333 0.083333333
97  Uno Derecho Antihorario 0.083333333 0.083333333
98  Uno Derecho Antihorario 0.166666667 0.166666667
100 Uno Derecho Antihorario 0   0
101 Uno Derecho Antihorario 0.166666667 0.166666667
102 Uno Derecho Antihorario 0.416666667 0.416666667
103 Uno Derecho Antihorario 0   0
104 Uno Derecho Antihorario -0.083333333    -0.083333333
105 Uno Derecho Antihorario 0   0
106 Uno Derecho Antihorario 0   0
108 Uno Derecho Antihorario -0.583333333    -0.583333333
109 Uno Derecho Antihorario 0   0
110 Uno Derecho Antihorario 0.166666667 0.166666667
111 Uno Derecho Antihorario -0.166666667    -0.166666667
```

Comment: Removing data to achieve "normality" is statistical malpractice.

Comment: Hi @42, Is there a non -parametrical test I can run on R within a linear mixed model? which is it? I'm just starting with statistics as well as using this program. Thanks a lot.

Comment: There are many. There's an entire CRAN Task View devoted to Robust Methods.